# jQuery form (Google Recaptcha on click)

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to add a recaptcha to my create account form. I'm using jQuery to manipulate the content so that I don't need to add another page just for account creation.

Here's the HTML:

```
          <form class="login" action="" method="post">
            <h3 id="titleaccount" style="color: #303030; margin: 10px auto; text-align: center;">Account Management</h3>
            <label>Username</label>
            <br />
            <input required="required" type="text" id="username">
            <div id="email"></div>
            <div id="emailform"></div>
            <label>Password</label>
            <br />
            <input required="required" type="password" id="password">
            <br />
            <div id="captcha">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<removed>"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="buttondiv"><input id="submitaccount" type="submit" value="Login"></div>
            <p id="forgot">Forgot your password? <a href="#openModal">Recover it</a>.</p>
            <p id="create">Don't have an account? <a id="createaccount" href="#">Create one</a>.</p>
        </form>
```

And here's the current JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
"use strict";
$( "#captcha" ).empty();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
"use strict";
    $( "#createaccount" ).click(function() {
        $( "#email" ).append( "<label>Email</label>" );
        $( "#buttondiv" ).empty();
        $( "#email" ).append( '<input required="required" type="text" id="emailcreate">' );
        $( "#buttondiv" ).append( '<input id="createaccount" type="submit" value="Create Account">' );
        $( "#captcha" ).append( '<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<removed>"></div>' );
        $( "#forgot" ).empty();
        $( "#create" ).empty();
    });
});
```

Appending the div for the recaptcha into the div of the captcha doesn't seem to work. Note that I'm emptying it as well because I don't want there to be a captcha for logging in.

Edit: It seems like it's actually appending the div but the captcha doesn't show up like it should.